# How to apply metadata for images and videos in AWS S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, metadata, amazon-cloudfront, media

I am updating metadata for each image so that it will be downloaded when clicking on images in my website. Each image is stored in AWS S3 bucket . So, currently i have to edit metadata for each image, how can i apply it to image folder which contains multiple image.

I am using below metadata for individual image apartments.JPG :

```
attachment;filename=apartments.JPG
```

But, i want this logic to apply to all the images of folder, how can i do for png and jpeg images.
I tried below also on images folder but it didnt work:

attachment;filename=*.JPG|*.png

Please help, i have attached screenshot of my s3 images folder and metadata info.

[image: metadata description for image]

[image: Image folder which contains all the images]

Comment: There is no builtin way for this: you need to list all the files in a bucket under a specific prefix and then modify the metadata for each, one by one...

Comment: You can use S3Events to trigger a Lambda whenever a file is uploaded to automate the process - but as @luk2302 says you still need to do it yourself.

Comment: Are you using presigned URL by any chance?

Comment: @jellycsc I am using URL like cloudfront_url/media/static/img/image1.jpg